# Замена значений на основе вхождения слова в строку другого столбца

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Не могу понять, как сделать следующее:

Есть столбец `keyword` и столбец `text`.
Что я хочу сделать? - если есть определенное слово в строке столбца text, то мы заменяем в этой же строке, НО В СТОЛБЦЕ keyword значение NaN на это слово.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я пытался сделать? -
заменил для удобства NaN на 0

`train['keyword'] = train['keyword'].fillna(0)`

далее решил пройтись по каждой строке столбца text, где keyword 0.

`a = train.query('keyword == 0')`

```
for i in a['text']:
if 'fire' in i:
    a.keyword.replace(0, 'fire', inplace=True)
```

Что в итоге получил? -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мы видим, заменились все 0 на данное слово.

P.S.

- Также пытался пройтись по двум циклам (цикл в цикле)
- Пытался заменить по индексу, соответсвующему индексу вхождения в строку слова.

Ссылка на [полный df](https://yadi.sk/d/7lFPBvvWmR1bWg)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё довольно просто, но надо уметь мыслить по-пандовски, "векторно":

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
word = 'fire'
df.loc[(df.text.str.contains(word)) & (df.keyword.isna()),'keyword'] = word
df
```

Вывод:

```
         id keyword  ...                                               text target
0         1     NaN  ...  Our Deeds are the Reason of this #earthquake M...      1
1         4    fire  ...             Forest fire near La Ronge Sask. Canada      1
2         5     NaN  ...  All residents asked to 'shelter in place' are ...      1
3         6    fire  ...  13,000 people receive #wildfires evacuation or...      1
4         7    fire  ...  Just got sent this photo from Ruby #Alaska as ...      1
...     ...     ...  ...                                                ...    ...
7608  10869     NaN  ...  Two giant cranes holding a bridge collapse int...      1
7609  10870    fire  ...  @aria_ahrary @TheTawniest The out of control w...      1
7610  10871     NaN  ...  M1.94 [01:04 UTC]?5km S of Volcano Hawaii. htt...      1
7611  10872     NaN  ...  Police investigating after an e-bike collided ...      1
7612  10873    fire  ...  The Latest: More Homes Razed by Northern Calif...      1

[7613 rows x 5 columns]
```

Я правда тут проверяю просто вхождение как подстроки, если надо по совпадению целых слов в предложении проверять, то надо будет ещё подумать.

Поясняю, что происходит в строке

```
df.loc[(df.text.str.contains(word)) & (df.keyword.isna()),'keyword'] = word
```

- `df.text.str.contains(word)` - делаем "маску", отмечая как `True` те строки, у которых в столбце `text` содержится слово из переменной `word`
- `df.keyword.isna()` - делаем "маску", отмечая как `True` те строки, у которых в столбце `keyword` содержится `NA`
- ("маска")&("маска") - объединяем две маски через логическое &, скобки в данном случае обязательны
- `df.loc["маска",'keyword'] = word` - берём те строки, у которых в "маске" стоит True и в них берём столбец `keyword`, ну и пишем в этот столбец наше слово во все эти выбранные строки

Comment: Как я понял, этот код будет менять и в остальных строках (не NaN) на слово, если таковое присутствует в столбце text. Также, получается, если у нас много слов помимо данного, т.е. если мы работаем уже с другими строками на нахождение вхождения в столбец других слов, то нам нужно сделать словарь и циклом проходиться изменяя другие NaN на нужные нам слова?

Comment: @ДимаВиноградов Вам нужно только строки где NaN так поменять? Легко. Сейчас изменю ответ

Comment: да, но я уже через свой код поменял) спасибо